# Unable to render 'bullet' chart via node-export-server from highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I've faced with issue when I unable to render the chart picture via [node-export-server](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server).
In response I've obtained the picture with error #17.
The same error occurs when I tried to put my chart data to [export.highlights.com](http://export.highcharts.com/)

```
{
    chart: {
        marginTop: 40,
        inverted: true,
        marginLeft: 135,
        type: 'bullet',
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: '2017 YTD'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['<span class="hc-cat-title">Revenue</span><br/>U.S. $ (1,000s)']
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridLineWidth: 0,
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 150,
            color: '#666'
        }, {
            from: 150,
            to: 225,
            color: '#999'
        }, {
            from: 225,
            to: 9e9,
            color: '#bbb'
        }],
        title: null
    },
    series: [{
        data: [{
            y: 275,
            target: 250
        }]
    }],
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b> (with target at {point.target})'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointPadding: 0.25,
            borderWidth: 0,
            color: '#000',
            targetOptions: {
                width: '200%'
            },
        },
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    }
}
```

Could you please advice where I was missing... 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `node-export-server` is not able to export the 'bullet' chart type at all. Here is the reported issue: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/157

I'll let you know when it will be fixed.

Comment: I just made fork of the project.. and added bullet module into list of modules and now it works. Just strange moment where they didn't add ability to select needed modules for export server.